# Unable to change border colour of Syncfusion MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion MaskedTextBox

```
@Html.EJS().MaskedTextBox("Name").Width("100%").Value(Model.Name).Render()
```

I want to change the border colour of the textbox if textbox is empty. I am doing

```
document.getElementById("Name").style.borderColor.red;
```

but it's not working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the EJS package and then trying to achieve your desired result, please find the code below. I have tried and tested this at my end. If the input box is empty then a red border will appear otherwise it will hide. You can use other JQuery methods like `.toggleClass()` to add appropriate styling to the elements. I hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {

                var input = document.getElementById('Name');
                if (input.value.length == "") {
                    input.style.border = "1px solid red";
                }
                else {
                    input.style.border = "none";
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            @Html.EJS().MaskedTextBox("Name").Width("100%").Render()

            @Html.EJS().Button("button").Content("Click Me").Render()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is incorrect format for border property, change to this

```
document.getElementById("Name").style.border = "1px solid red";
```